# Execute remote powershell script from local system

Tags: vb.net, powershell-2.0, remote-desktop, localsystem

I am new to this powershell..Execuse me if anything wrong here.

Now coming straight to the question I have a powershell script stored in one of the drive say `"D:\myfile.ps1"` which is in remote system.

Now I need to execute this script from my local system and this is the way I have done

```
ExecuteCommand(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Psexec \\myservername -i -u username -p password powershell.exe Invoke-Command -ComputerName \\myservername -FilePath D:\myscript.ps1")
```

The result is showing me this way without any output giving me an error

***`"powershell exited on myservername with error code 1'`***

[image]

And If run this script to run .exe on the same server it's working fine

```
ExecuteCommand(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\psexec \\myservername -u username -p password D:\myfile.exe")
```

So what's the correct way to execute my script to run on remote desktop ?

**Update after suggestions:**

[image]

Comment: It could be a UAC problem? Try right click and run as admin to test this theory.

Comment: @MattWilko-Based on your suggestion, I have tried running it as an admin by using Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs but that too gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try :

```
ExecuteCommand(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Psexec \\myservername -i -u username -p password powershell.exe -command  "&{Invoke-Command -ComputerName \\myservername -FilePath D:\myscript.ps1}"
```

Comment: @JPBlanc-It's giving me some blue dots indicated as errors to double quotes after "&" So I have changed it to this ExecuteCommand(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Psexec \\myservername  -i -u username  -p password  powershell.exe -command  " & "{Invoke-Command -ComputerName \\myservername   -FilePath D:\FreeSpace.ps1}") and now it's giving me as powershell exited on myservername with error code 0 and added screenshot of it.